# Open ID for My URL

Tags: asp.net

I have My own Domain `shakarganj.com.pk` and I want to Use google Open ID for this Domain and want to use domain email as openid for my web pages.And also want to get log of who is accessing my web page from which email address.

I am using Open Id Control with following code but it only works with all gmail accoutns i need with my domain email like `mailk.adeel@shakarganj.com`

```
<rp:OpenIdLogin runat=server Identifier="https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id" Visible=false ExampleUrl="" LabelText=" " RegisterText=" "    ExamplePrefix=" " ID="OpenIdLogin1" ></rp:OpenIdLogin>
```

this is the exampel what i want

http://samples.dotnetopenauth.net/v3.4/OpenIdRelyingPartyWebForms/loginGoogleApps.aspx

If i give my domain email like malik.adeel@shakarganj.com.pk it goes to mail.shakarganj.com.pk and authenticate only domain user to acces the form please now tell me how can i do this like this

Comment: please show some source code... what have you tried ? what is not working ?

Comment: I write my code please give me some proper and exact solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You question is not at all clear and hard to answer,but as per the initial information here are some inputs

1. Google OpenID will only work for the Google account holder.

basically Google is an Open-ID provider which means for all Google account holder ,it provides an open-ID for them, so it will only work for its own domain.

that's said,can only provide other information if you provides details what you want and what you trying to achieve

Comment: I only trying to achieve that when i press login button in should goes to mail.shakarganj.com.pk domain for authentiation not all gmail accounts

Comment: Sir i have updated my question please give me some solution for this